# jquery selector: how can I use JQuery to select the child of a parent?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, parent

I was wondering how I could use JQuery to select the child of a parent?

I have the following.

```
$("#navigation a.subpage").click(function () {
  $("#navigation ul ul")...
```

The HTML looks like this.

```
<li>
  <a class="subpage"...</a>
  <ul style="hidden">...</ul>
</li>
```

I need to somehow select the parents of the link. That would get me the relevant li. Then I need to select the ul and toggle it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
$("a.subpage").click(function() {
  $(this).next().toggle();
  return false;
});
```

`this` in an event handler is the source of the event, being the link.

**Edit:** the issue of whether or not `next()` is appropriate. Of course if the markup is different you use a different chain. There are *many* ways of achieving the same result, for example:

```
$(this).siblings("ul").toggle();
```

But what if the link is inside a paragraph?

```
$(this).closest("li").children("ul").toggle();
```

But what if the list isn't a direct child?

Etc etc etc. All of these are reasonable approaches but keep it simple: Write your jQuery code to suit your markup rather than trying to cater for things that don't happen and probably never will.

Comment: Or you can keep the #navigation in the context of the selector for optimization:

    $("a.subpage", "#navigation").click(...

Comment: I would prefer $(this).next('ul').toggle(); // takes care if some element is added in between.

Comment: The problem will remain if the added element between is another <ul>   ;)

Comment: @mohang: `.next()` doesn't work like this...I agree it's not intuitive, see my comment on the `.next()` documentation page: http://api.jquery.com/next/ You need `.nextAll('ul:first')` for that.

Answer (score 3):

If it's the next item always, then [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) works, if there may be something in-between use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), like this:

```
$("#navigation a.subpage").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('ul').toggle();
  return false;
});
```

[You can find the list of traversal functions here](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) :)

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).parent().find('ul').toggle()`